# Is there a function to add error bars with discrete values to monthly dataset ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, range

I have a dataset of average monthly temperature values from jan-december. I have plotted these on a line graph and ensured that the months are read as factors for  plotting.

I also have the maximum and minimum temperature values for each month. I would like to add these as error/range bars onto the plot, but using geom_errorbar(), an error of 'Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale' comes up.

Can someone help me with this?

Here is my current code for the graph without error bars:

```
#Orkeny.HADISST.1893.2016.SST
Orkeny.HADISST.1893.2016.SST$Month = factor(Orkeny.HADISST.1893.2016.SST$Month, levels = month.abb)
ggplot(data=Orkeny.HADISST.1893.2016.SST)+
  aes(x = Month, y =VariableValue, group=1) +
  geom_point(colour='Blue')+
  geom_line(colour='Blue')+
  xlab('Month')+
  ylab('Average Sea Surface Temperature 1893-2016 (°C)')
```

See below an image of the dataset I am using. It is the 'Min' and 'Max' I would like to add as error/range bars

[Image of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6y3f.png)

Comment: Could you please share your dataset using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see what you already tried. But I think you may have mixed up the x and y axis.

When I recreate your df

```
month<-c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Juli","Aug",
         "Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")

value<-c(8.0, 7.5, 7.3, 7.7, 8.8, 10.6, 12.1, 12.8, 12.0,
         11.1,9.9,8.8)

min<-c(7, 6.5, 6.2, 6.8, 7.6, 9.4, 10.8, 11.5, 10.9, 10.1,
       8.2, 8)

max<-c(9.1,8.8,8.3,8.8,10.2,11.9,13.7,14.8,13.3,12.3,11.3,10)

df<-data.frame(month,value,min,max)
```

I can plot it with the desired error_bar by using

```
p1 <-ggplot(data=df,aes(x=value, y= month))+
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=min,
                     xmax= max))+
  geom_point(aes(),shape=16, size=2)

p1
```

Or like this:

```
p2 <-ggplot(data=df,aes(x=month, y= value))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=min,
                     ymax= max))+
  geom_point(aes(),shape=16, size=2)

p2
```

Do you see how the

```
geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=min,
                   xmax= max))

geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=min,
                  ymax= max))
```

command changes depending on where you have the factors (month).

Your problem is probably that you want to assign the factor to a continuous scale. This is what R is trying to tell you with:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale